# How to write JSONConverter to trim whitespaces from the <string> ICollection elements

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

Our Web API receives a collection of strings with extra spaces in the collection items. I want to write a generic JSON Converter attribute that can be used to trim spaces for each elements of the collection.

If the JSON is like this :

```
prop:["value1  ","    value2" ]
```

I want this to translated at the API as

```
Prop : [ "value1", "value2"]
```

I am using FromBody attribute to translate JSON directly to its entity class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would try to do the conversion on the class itself in the property getter or setter.
But if you really want to, you could create a custom JsonConverter to do it like this:

```
public class StringCollectionTrimmerJsonConverter : JsonConverter<IEnumerable<string>>
{
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable<string> value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<string> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, IEnumerable<string> existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> strings = null;

        if (reader.TokenType.Equals(JsonToken.StartArray))
        {
            JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
            strings = token.ToObject<IEnumerable<string>>().Select((s) => s?.Trim());
        }

        return strings ?? new string[] { };
    }
}
```

You can then decorate your class property like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringCollectionTrimmerJsonConverter))]
public IEnumerable<string> SomeValues { get; set; }
```

See the various documentations at: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConverterAttributeProperty.htm